# What work is needed to pre-populate input form values using the URL/query strings?

Tags: forms, http, query-string

I am creating a web portal. I have a button on the portal which redirects the user to a different website (owned by us but completely different website). I would like to pre-fill some of the input fields on a form with data passed from the portal (First name, last name and email).

I understand you can use query strings in the URL to populate fields on a form. I have tried using mywebsite.com/page/?FirstName=Jane but it is not populating the input fields. This method seems ideal but I assume there may be some work to do on the separate website to get this to work.

Both my portal and the other website is built with asp.net mvc.

Can anyone confirm if can get away with passing parameters without modifying the different website?

Comment: You can use ajax to get data and use script to populate data to form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since I've done mvc.

if you want to link with mywebsite.com/page/?FirstName=Jane

Assuming you have control over the page you're linking to, the page that you link to needs to 
1.  The model needs to have firstName in it

```
public class SomeModel
{
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "First name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

2. The controller needs to populate it from that query string

   public ActionResult Index(SomeModel model)
   {
   return View(model);
   }
3. The view needs to use it

@model Site.Models.SomeModel

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it makes sense. Do you know if there is a way to get these form input fields to populate without amending the different website? It will be hard to modify and redeploy it.

Comment: if you are trying to access an outside website... you're probably very limited.  If they're on the same domain (which I t suspect is unlikely), you might be able to do it via java script, but otherwise there are security featues in javascript specifically to block you from doing what you're asking